# how to convert msgstore.db.crypt7 to msgstore.db from whatsapp in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want add Automatically contacts that message to me in Whatsapp, so I need to access to Whatsapp's database for my program, but Whatsapp's database is not in `.db` format and is in `.crypt7` format and I cannot use it. How can I use Whatsapp db or convert `.crypt7` to `.db`?

Comment: `but whatsapps database is not .db format` ... **luckily**! It's a major **security** feature (i.e.: **privacy**). Ask WhatsApp developers how to **reverse engineer** their db.

Comment: [Maybe this](http://www.digitalinternals.com/security/decrypt-whatsapp-crypt7-database-messages/307/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ashesh mentioned you can use the tool on the XDA developer website: 
[[TOOL] Whatsapp Xtract: Backup Messages Extractor / Database Analyzer / Chat-Backup](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1583021)

Alternatively you can do this manually as follows:

The WhatsApp Database is stored **unencrypted** at this path on the Android device:

```
/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db
```

Backups of the database are also stored **encrypted** on the SD card typically at the following location:

```
/sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt7
```

The unique key for the encrypted backup databases is stored here:

```
/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key
```

Access to the /data/data directory requires root access. Alternatively ADB (Android Debug Bridge) can be used to extract the above files after booting into recovery on the device.

**How to Decrypt WhatsApp crypt7 Database Messages:**

*(commands below are run from a linux enviroment)*

1. Extract Key File: /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key
2. Extract crypt7 file: /sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt7
3. Extract Decryption Keys from "key" file extracted in step 1:

   - 256-bit AES key:

     `hexdump -e '2/1 "%02x"' key | cut -b 253-316 > aes.txt`
   - IV (initialisation vector):

     `hexdump -e '2/1 "%02x"' key | cut -b 221-252 > iv.txt`
4. Strip Header in crypt7 File:

   `dd if=msgstore.db.crypt7 of=msgstore.db.crypt7.nohdr ibs=67 skip=1`

   *Note: Size of header stripped file in bytes must be divisible by 16*
5. Decrypt crypt7 File:

   `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -nosalt -nopad -bufsize 16384 -in msgstore.db.crypt7.nohdr -K $(cat aes.txt) -iv $(cat iv.txt) > msgstore.db`

Answer (score 0):

Developers at XDA have made tools to perform such operations.

Here is one (windows only)

[[TOOL] Whatsapp Xtract](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1583021)

It's old but I'm sure there will be newer ones out there.